# Owl carousel autoplaySpeed

Tags: jquery, css, html, owl-carousel

I am using Owl Carousel for smooth scrolling and It is working fine,
But when I hover the mouse on the slider it stops (which is correct) but its taking time to stop, not getting stop instantly.

Is there anything we can do with it to stop instantly on mouse-hover.

Here what I have done so far.

-- HTML

```
<div id="review-wrapper" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
<div class="item">
    <div class="review-block">
        <p><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <div class="review-text"><p>“Very professional from start to finish delivered what they promised. Charlie
            the gentleman who picked up my bike 100%”</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-block">
        <p><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <div class="review-text"><p>“Very professional from start to finish delivered what they promised. Charlie
            the gentleman who picked up my bike 100%”</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="review-block">
        <p><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <div class="review-text"><p>“Very professional from start to finish delivered what they promised. Charlie
            the gentleman who picked up my bike 100%”</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-block">
        <p><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <div class="review-text"><p>“Very professional from start to finish delivered what they promised. Charlie
            the gentleman who picked up my bike 100%”</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="review-block">
        <p><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <div class="review-text"><p>“Very professional from start to finish delivered what they promised. Charlie
            the gentleman who picked up my bike 100%”</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-block">
        <p><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i
                class="fa fa-star-half-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
        <div class="review-text"><p>“Very professional from start to finish delivered what they promised. Charlie
            the gentleman who picked up my bike 100%”</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

-- JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
        owl.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            //slideTransition: 'linear',
            autoplayTimeout: 0,
            autoplaySpeed: 8000,
            center: true,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1,
                    autoplay: false,
                },
                600: {
                    items: 2,
                    autoplay: true,
                },
                1000: {
                    items: 7,
                    autoplay: true,
                }
            }
        });

    $('#review-wrapper .item').on('mouseenter', function (e) {
                //alert(111);
                //owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
                owl.owlCarousel({autoplaySpeed: 100,});
            })

            $('#review-wrapper .item').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay')
            })
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to stop autoplay on hover?

Comment: Yes. And its getting stop also but not instantly. its take time to stop